# SetPixel() too slow to erase image background

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm working on window phone application. I want to erase background of an image. I'm using setpixel() method for it. But it erasing background very slow.Here is my code.

```
 private void Canvas_MouseMove_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            wrt = new WriteableBitmap(imag, null);
            try
            {
                System.Windows.Media.Color c = new System.Windows.Media.Color();
                c.A = 0;
                c.B = 0; c.R = 0; c.G = 0;
                currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this.imag);

            for (int degrees = 0; degrees <= 360; degrees++)
            {
                for (int distance = 0; distance <= erasersize; distance++)
                {
                    //double angle = Math.PI * degrees / 180.0;
                    double x = currentPoint.X + (distance * Math.Cos(degrees));
                    double y = currentPoint.Y + (distance * Math.Sin(degrees));
                    wrt.SetPixel(Convert.ToInt32(x), Convert.ToInt32(y) - offset, c);
                }
            }

        }
```

I've searched many articles in google , but noone worked for me. One of the method Bitmap.LockBits suggested to me. But the problem is we cannot add system.drawing into window phone app, because dll not supported.
Can anyone help me to solve this out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you just trying to fade or remove the image.  If so, you use an animation to set the opacity level of the image.

Comment: @WaltRitscher  Thanks for reply.Actually I've to remove background of an image and save some portion of image in which I can use other background.. My code is erasing background but setpixel() works slow that's why i cannot achive the quality of eraser what actually i needed....

Answer (score 1):

`WriteableBitmap` has nice property called `Pixels`. It's just an array of integers but it gives you much faster way to manipulate pixels.

First, you need fast color-to-int conventer:

```
public static int ColorToInt(Color color)
{
    return unchecked((int)((color.A << 24) | (color.R << 16) | (color.G << 8) | color.B));
}
```

Then you can change your code:

```
wrt = new WriteableBitmap(imag, null);
try
{
    System.Windows.Media.Color c = new System.Windows.Media.Color();
    c.A = 0;
    c.B = 0; c.R = 0; c.G = 0;
    currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this.imag);

    int width = wrt.PixelWidth;

    for (int degrees = 0; degrees <= 360; degrees++)
    {
        for (int distance = 0; distance <= erasersize; distance++)
        {
            //double angle = Math.PI * degrees / 180.0;
            double x = currentPoint.X + (distance * Math.Cos(degrees));
            double y = currentPoint.Y + (distance * Math.Sin(degrees));
            wrt.Pixels[(int)(y - offset) * width + (int)x] = ColorToInt(c);
        }
    }
}
```