# Generate a circle where user taps(Clicks) in window phone8 App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, geometry

I want to use the functionality in my window phone8 App that a circle should be generated where a user clicks on the phone screen. In android and IOS there is an event Touchpose. Is there any Equivalent method of touchpose in wp8. 
or any other way to create a circle on screen where user taps(clicks). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can. If your layout is based on a grid, then here's my example how you can do this.

XAML:

```
<Page /* all the default stuff */>
    <Grid Tapped="Grid_Tapped" Background="Black">
        // Your content
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

C#:

```
private void Grid_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse()
    {
        Width = 64,
        Height = 64,
        Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
        Opacity = 0.2,
        IsHitTestVisible = false, // This makes the circle transparent for touch, so you can tap things under it.
    };
    Grid.SetColumnSpan(ellipse, 99); // You need this if you have more columns than one.
    Grid.SetRowSpan(ellipse, 99); // You need this if you have more rows than one.
    Point position = e.GetPosition((Grid)sender);
    ellipse.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top; // This will allow us to use top margin as Y coordinate.
    ellipse.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left; // This will allow us to use left margin as X coordinate.
    ellipse.Margin = new Thickness(position.X - ellipse.Width / 2, position.Y - ellipse.Height / 2, 0, 0); // Place the circle where user taps.

    ((Grid)sender).Children.Add(ellipse);
}
```

Note that the background of the main grid cannot be transparent, otherwise it won't fire `Tapped` event.

If you want, you can also animate the circle, change its size and color, make it disappear after some time...

Comment: Hi @Lukasz.. Thanks for your answer. It is generating circle at the point where user click but i want to  to move that circle on mouse move event.
This code is for removing image background
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28577625/setpixel-too-slow-to-erase-image-background

but I'm not able to show a circle where user moving mouse.

Please suggest me something for this,

Many thanks in advance..

Comment: But there is no mouse in Windows Phone. You mean touch, when user drag the screen?